# MVC Controller Action cookie.add not persisting after jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

In my view I have a jQuery script that fires on a dropdown list change. It calls a Controller Action that performs various logic and then either updates or adds a cookie. I'm finding that the cookie is not getting created and I suspect it's because the jQuery is reloading the page.

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#SelectedLanguage').on('change', function () {
            var culture = $(this).val();
            $('#test').load("/Account/TestPartial/" + culture, function () {
            location.reload(true);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Code called by Controller Action:**

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null
    && Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Culture"] != null)
{
    var existingCookie = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"];
    existingCookie.Values["Culture"] = SelectedLanguage;
    existingCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(50 * 365);
    Response.Cookies.Set(existingCookie);
}
else
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    cookie.Values["Culture"] = SelectedLanguage;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Is it accurate that the Response.Cookies.Add() will succeed but the cookie will not be written due to the `location.reload(true);` on return?

If so, is there any way around this? I'm needing the cookie to exist once the reload is finished.

If this isn't the problem, does anyone see why the cookie wouldn't exist after reload?

Comment: Did you check the HTTP headers on the response using something like fiddler to make sure the setcookie value is actually there?

Comment: Alex, I hadn't looked at Fiddler traffic since I made changes that appeared to make everything work. Now that you pointed me to Fiddler I see the return from my Controller Action is throwing an HTTP 500 error because it can't find the PartialView named as the Controller Action I'm calling. This is probably the issue, you think? :P I'll work on it. Thx.